# Is Google Content API for Shopping compatible with CE 1.9?

Tags: magento-1.9, google-api

I'm looking to export a basic data feed from Magento CE 1.9. I understand that there is a free extension called Google Content API for Shopping. However, the product description only says it is compatible with 1.6 and 1.7. 
Is there a version compatiable with 1.9?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See That Extension is developed by the [MAGENTO](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/google-content-api-for-shopping.html).

So they mention on site like support up to 1.7.

As per My experience if they the Module is not override any core functionality then It will work in 1.8 as well as 1.9.

you can try to install in local machine If everything is working fine then you can use for your live site :)

Comment: Thanks. I've installed the latest version but I can't get it to work. 

I tried the following:
Account ID = My Merchant Account ID
Account Login = My Google User Name
Account Password = My Google Password
Account Type = Google
When I tried to upload a product:

The product cannot be added to Google Content. Unable to connect to Google Content. Please, check Account settings in configuration.Error: Unable to Connect to ssl://www.google.com:443. Error #110: connection timed out

Answer (score 1):

Hello you can also check these extension that extension is working fine if you don't mind then you can use that.

https://github.com/5mehulhelp5/MagentoExtensions